# Connect iPhone application to flash media server

Tags: iphone, flash, messaging, rtmp

I Have a flash player application embedded with a website working fine. Now I want to do it in iPhone, fore that i want to send request to flash server. The responses from server are realtime and used RTMP. How can I send request to Flash server from my iPhone application.

Answer (score 0):

I've ported my app on iPad. And I didn't changed code that performs interaction with server